# C++ function that is const &

Tags: c++, c++11

I recently came across code that looks like this:

```
const T& operator*() const &;
```

I know that usually when 'const' follows a function, it indicates that this function does not change member data but I am not sure what the significance of the '&' is. I only see it on the dereferencing operator so I assume it has something to do with that.

Comment: You're asking about orthogonal things.